# Spring mvc <form:input> tags with some values passed from the calling controller in modelAttribute

Tags: spring-mvc

I am creating CRUD application in Spring MVC 3. Every thing is working fine apart from the edit page. I want my edit page to be populated with with some  tags with relevant database generated values, so I can see, edit if I want and save them. I passed list of values in modelAttribute to share with the edit.jsp. I can retrieve them values on edit.jsp, however I am unable to put those values in  tag, as it doesn't have a value attribute. Please help.

```
Sharing the code below----------------------------

    enter code here
<form:form id="form5" commandName="user" action="modify.htm">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
        <tr>
            <td> <form:input path="name" value="${user.name}"/></td>
            <td><form:input path="age" value="{user.age}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    <tr><td><button type="button" onclick="modify()">Save</button></td></tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no value attribute for form:input (as you guessed). The data binding path has to be mentioned in path attribute only. So, as per my understanding of your problem, the solution is as below:

You have User class:

```
public class User{
    String name;
    String age;
    //Getter setters..
}
```

You need a command/model object class to hold list of UserS so can be used in view (as below)

```
public class Users {
    List<User> userList; 
    //Getter setter..
}
```

Your controller handler method might add Users to the model

```
Users users = getUsers(); // Get them from somewhere(DB) and wrap in Users object
model.addAttribute("users", users);
```

Use in jsp as below:

```
<form:form id="form5" modelAttribute="users" action="modify.htm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
       <c:forEach items="${users.userList}" var="user" varStatus="i">
            <tr>
                <td><form:input path="userList[${i.index}].name" /></td>
                <td<form:input path="userList[${i.index}].age" /></td>
            </tr>
       </c:forEach>
       <tr><td><button type="button" onclick="modify()">Save</button></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I understood what you have suggested, but at the moment I am getting java.lang.NumberFormatException. I look into it a bit later, and I will reply back about the result. Thanks "Vinay" for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Couldn't you use user.name instead of userList[${i.index}].name?